# Convert String to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn using VB.Net and Access

Tags: vb.net, string, ms-access, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Can't find anything on the internet, I'm thinking I'm missing something small.

I've got a list of column names in an access database, which should match DataGridViewTextBoxColumn I've created in my vb.net project. I want to use the column names in the access database to call the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn into  my dgv. Sample code below:

```
    Dim column1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim column2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim myheader As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    With column1
        .Name = "column1"
        .HeaderText = "Column 1"
        .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        .Width = 200
    End With

    With column2
        .Name = "column2"
        .HeaderText = "Column 2"
        .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        .Width = 400
    End With

    a = 0

    Do While a < 2
        myheader = ds.Tables("columnheadersdatabase").Rows(a).Item("J001") '//rows(a) = column1 and rows(a + 1) = column2
        dgv.Columns.Add(myheader)
        a += 1
    Loop
```

the problem area is the below:

```
        myheader = ds.Tables("columnheadersdatabase").Rows(a).Item("J001") '//rows(a) = column1 and rows(a + 1) = column2
        dgv.Columns.Add(myheader)
```

I can seem to convert my access cell value to my DataGridViewTextBoxColumn (myheader). I tried using dim myheader as string, but that also doesn't work.

Has anybody got any ideas, any help will be much apprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` objects can be stored in a list. A function can check whether an item of that list must be added in the columns collection of the DataGridView.

Try the following code:

```
'Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Test data
        'Dim ds As New DataSet
        'Dim tb As New DataTable("columnheadersdatabase")
        'tb.Columns.Add("J001")

        'tb.Rows.Add(tb.NewRow)
        'tb.Rows.Add(tb.NewRow)
        'tb.Rows.Add(tb.NewRow)

        'tb(0).Item("J001") = "column1"
        'tb(1).Item("J001") = "column2"
        'tb(2).Item("J001") = "column3"

        'ds.Tables.Add(tb)

        'A list that will contain all the DataGridViewTextBoxColumns
        Dim TextBoxColumnList As New List(Of DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)
        Dim column1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With
            {
                .Name = "column1",
                .HeaderText = "Column 1",
                .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable,
                .Width = 200
            }
        Dim column2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With
            {
                .Name = "column2",
                .HeaderText = "Column 2",
                .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable,
                .Width = 400
            }

        'The column1, column2 DataGridViewTextBoxColumns are being added in the list
        TextBoxColumnList.Add(column1)
        TextBoxColumnList.Add(column2)

        Dim a As Integer = 0

        Do While a < 2
            'Reads the name of the column from the datatable
            Dim ColumnName As String = ds.Tables("columnheadersdatabase").Rows(a).Item("J001").ToString
            'Searches the index of the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn from the list that has the
            'same name as the column name that was read from the datatable
            Dim ColumnIndex As Integer = GetColumnIndex(TextBoxColumnList, ColumnName)
            'Checks whether the index has been found
            If ColumnIndex <> -1 Then
                'Adds the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn in the DataGridView
                dgv.Columns.Add(TextBoxColumnList(ColumnIndex))
            End If

            a += 1
        Loop

    'End Sub

    Private Function GetColumnIndex(ByVal TextBoxColumnList As List(Of DataGridViewTextBoxColumn), ByVal ColumnName As String) As Integer
        'Checks whether the list has an object reference
        If TextBoxColumnList Is Nothing Then
            Return -1
        End If

        Dim i As Integer
        'Loops for all the items of the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn list
        For i = 0 To TextBoxColumnList.Count - 1
            'Compares the names
            If TextBoxColumnList(i).Name.ToUpper = ColumnName.ToUpper Then
                Return i
            End If
        Next

        Return -1
    End Function
```